# Как объяснить генетическому алгоритму для составления расписания занятий, что у меня есть пары, которые ведут сразу два преподавателя?

Tags: c#, генетический-алгоритм

Я начинающий непрограммист (студент), получил задание на дипломную работу, создание информационной системы, для формирования автоматического расписания занятий в учебном заведение, я продвинулся до составления генетического алгоритма на c# (взял немного тут, немного там склеил, разобрался и сейчас всё работает), но существует проблема, как объяснить алгоритму, что существуют занятия, в которых ведут сразу два преподавателя?
Ввод и вывод данных происходит посредством однострочных txt файликов.
Надеюсь, среди замечательных программистов найдется тот, кто поможет мне решить эту проблему.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Построение расписание начато, ожидайте");
            StreamWriter sw1 = new StreamWriter("D:\\Error.txt");
            try
            {
                //Pass the filepath and filename to the StreamWriter Constructor
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("D:\\SchedulePerWeek.txt");
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("D:\\Groups.txt");
            string groupline=sr.ReadLine();
            var groupslineint = groupline.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
                int[] groups=new int[groupslineint.Length];
                for (int i=0; i<groupslineint.Length;i++) {
                    groups[i] = groupslineint[i];
                }
                sw1.WriteLine(groups);
                sr.Close();
                StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader("D:\\Teachers.txt");
            string teachersline = sr1.ReadLine();
                var teacherslineint = teachersline.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
                int[] teachers = new int[teacherslineint.Length];
                for (int i = 0; i < teacherslineint.Length; i++)
                {
                    teachers[i] = teacherslineint[i];          
                }
                sw1.WriteLine(teachers);
                var list = new List<Lessоn>();
            for (int i = 0; i < groups.Length; i++)
                list.Add(new Lessоn(groups[i], teachers[i]));



        var solver = new Solver();//создаем решатель

        Plan.DaysPerWeek = 6;// Количество учебных дней
        Plan.HoursPerDay = 6;// Количество пар в одном дне

        solver.FitnessFunctions.Add(FitnessFunctions.Windows);//будем штрафовать за окна
        solver.FitnessFunctions.Add(FitnessFunctions.LateLesson);//будем штрафовать за поздние пары

        var res = solver.Solve(list);//находим лучший план
    
            sw.WriteLine(res);
            sw.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Расписание готово, пожайлуста закройте консоль.");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            sw1.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Ошибка при создании расписания, вызовете администратора");
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + e.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            sw1.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
            Console.WriteLine("Executing finally block.");
            sw1.Close();
        }
        sw1.Close();
    }
}



/// <summary>
/// Фитнесс функции
/// </summary>
static class FitnessFunctions
{
    public static int GroupWindowPenalty = 10;//штраф за окно у группы
    public static int TeacherWindowPenalty = 7;//штраф за окно у преподавателя
    public static int LateLessonPenalty = 1;//штраф за позднюю пару

    public static int LatesetHour = 4;//максимальный час, когда удобно проводить пары

    /// <summary>
    /// Штраф за окна
    /// </summary>
    public static int Windows(Plan plan)
    {
        var res = 0;

        for (byte day = 0; day < Plan.DaysPerWeek; day++)
        {
            

            var groupHasLessions = new HashSet<int>();
            var teacherHasLessions = new HashSet<int>();

            for (byte hour = 0; hour < Plan.HoursPerDay; hour++)
            {
                foreach (var pair in plan.HourPlans[day, hour].GroupToTeacher)
                {
                    var group = pair.Key;
                    var teacher = pair.Value;
                    if (groupHasLessions.Contains(group) && !plan.HourPlans[day, hour - 1].GroupToTeacher.ContainsKey(group))
                        res += GroupWindowPenalty;
                    if (teacherHasLessions.Contains(teacher) && !plan.HourPlans[day, hour - 1].TeacherToGroup.ContainsKey(teacher))
                        res += TeacherWindowPenalty;

                    groupHasLessions.Add(group);
                    teacherHasLessions.Add(teacher);

                }
            }
        }

        return res;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Штраф за поздние пары
    /// </summary>
    public static int LateLesson(Plan plan)
    {
        var res = 0;
        foreach (var pair in plan.GetLessons())
            if (pair.Hour > LatesetHour)
                res += LateLessonPenalty;

        return res;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Решатель (генетический алгоритм)
/// </summary>
class Solver
{
    public int MaxIterations = 1000;
    public int PopulationCount = 1000;//должно делиться на 4

    public List<Func<Plan, int>> FitnessFunctions = new List<Func<Plan, int>>();

    public int Fitness(Plan plan)
    {
        var res = 0;

        foreach (var f in FitnessFunctions)
            res += f(plan);

        return res;
    }

    public Plan Solve(List<Lessоn> pairs)
    {
        //создаем популяцию
        var pop = new Population(pairs, PopulationCount);
        if (pop.Count == 0)
            throw new Exception("Can not create any plan");
        //
        var count = MaxIterations;
        while (count-- > 0)
        {
            //считаем фитнесс функцию для всех планов
            pop.ForEach(p => p.FitnessValue = Fitness(p));
            //сортруем популяцию по фитнесс функции
            pop.Sort((p1, p2) => p1.FitnessValue.CompareTo(p2.FitnessValue));
            //найден идеальный план?
            if (pop[0].FitnessValue == 0)
                return pop[0];
            //отбираем 25% лучших планов
            pop.RemoveRange(pop.Count / 4, pop.Count - pop.Count / 4);
            //от каждого создаем трех потомков с мутациями
            var c = pop.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < c; i++)
            {
                pop.AddChildOfParent(pop[i]);
                pop.AddChildOfParent(pop[i]);
                pop.AddChildOfParent(pop[i]);
            }
        }

        //считаем фитнесс функцию для всех планов
        pop.ForEach(p => p.FitnessValue = Fitness(p));
        //сортруем популяцию по фитнесс функции
        pop.Sort((p1, p2) => p1.FitnessValue.CompareTo(p2.FitnessValue));

        //возвращаем лучший план
        return pop[0];
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Популяция планов
/// </summary>
class Population : List<Plan>
{
    public Population(List<Lessоn> pairs, int count)
    {
        var maxIterations = count * 2;

        do
        {
            var plan = new Plan();
            if (plan.Init(pairs))
                Add(plan);
        } while (maxIterations-- > 0 && Count < count);
    }

    public bool AddChildOfParent(Plan parent)
    {
        int maxIterations = 10;

        do
        {
            var plan = new Plan();
            if (plan.Init(parent))
            {
                Add(plan);
                return true;
            }
        } while (maxIterations-- > 0);
        return false;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// План занятий
/// </summary>
class Plan
{
    public static int DaysPerWeek = 6;//6 учебных дня в неделю
    public static int HoursPerDay = 7;//до 6 пар в день

    static Random rnd = new Random(3);

    /// <summary>
    /// План по дням (первый индекс) и часам (второй индекс)
    /// </summary>
    public HourPlan[,] HourPlans = new HourPlan[DaysPerWeek, HoursPerDay];

    public int FitnessValue { get; internal set; }

    public bool AddLesson(Lessоn les)
    {
        return HourPlans[les.Day, les.Hour].AddLesson(les.Group, les.Teacher);
    }

    public void RemoveLesson(Lessоn les)
    {
        HourPlans[les.Day, les.Hour].RemoveLesson(les.Group, les.Teacher);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавить группу с преподователем на любой день и любой час
    /// </summary>
    public bool AddToAnyDayAndHour(int group, int teacher)
    {
        int maxIterations = 30;
        do
        {
            var day = (byte)rnd.Next(DaysPerWeek);
            if (AddToAnyHour(day, group, teacher))
                return true;
        } while (maxIterations-- > 0);

        return false;//не смогли добавить никуда
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Добавить группу с преподом на любой час
    /// </summary>
    bool AddToAnyHour(byte day, int group, int teacher)
    {
        for (byte hour = 0; hour < HoursPerDay; hour++)
        {
            var les = new Lessоn(day, hour, group, teacher);
            if (AddLesson(les))
                return true;
        }

        return false;//нет свободных часов в этот день
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Создание плана по списку пар
    /// </summary>
    public bool Init(List<Lessоn> pairs)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < HoursPerDay; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < DaysPerWeek; j++)
                HourPlans[j, i] = new HourPlan();

        foreach (var p in pairs)
            if (!AddToAnyDayAndHour(p.Group, p.Teacher))
                return false;
        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Создание наследника с мутацией
    /// </summary>
    public bool Init(Plan parent)
    {
        //копируем предка
        for (int i = 0; i < HoursPerDay; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < DaysPerWeek; j++)
                HourPlans[j, i] = parent.HourPlans[j, i].Clone();

        //выбираем два случайных дня
        var day1 = (byte)rnd.Next(DaysPerWeek);
        var day2 = (byte)rnd.Next(DaysPerWeek);

        //находим пары в эти дни
        var pairs1 = GetLessonsOfDay(day1).ToList();
        var pairs2 = GetLessonsOfDay(day2).ToList();

        //выбираем случайные пары
        if (pairs1.Count == 0 || pairs2.Count == 0) return false;
        var pair1 = pairs1[rnd.Next(pairs1.Count)];
        var pair2 = pairs2[rnd.Next(pairs2.Count)];

        //создаем мутацию - переставляем случайные пары местами
        RemoveLesson(pair1);//удаляем
        RemoveLesson(pair2);//удаляем
        var res1 = AddToAnyHour(pair2.Day, pair1.Group, pair1.Teacher);//вставляем в случайное место
        var res2 = AddToAnyHour(pair1.Day, pair2.Group, pair2.Teacher);//вставляем в случайное место
        return res1 && res2;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Lessоn> GetLessonsOfDay(byte day)
    {
        for (byte hour = 0; hour < HoursPerDay; hour++)
            foreach (var p in HourPlans[day, hour].GroupToTeacher)
                yield return new Lessоn(day, hour, p.Key, p.Value);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Lessоn> GetLessons()
    {
        for (byte day = 0; day < DaysPerWeek; day++)
            for (byte hour = 0; hour < HoursPerDay; hour++)
                foreach (var p in HourPlans[day, hour].GroupToTeacher)
                    yield return new Lessоn(day, hour, p.Key, p.Value);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte day = 0; day < Plan.DaysPerWeek; day++)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("Day {0}\r\n", day);
            for (byte hour = 0; hour < Plan.HoursPerDay; hour++)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("Para {0}: ", hour);
                foreach (var p in HourPlans[day, hour].GroupToTeacher)
                    sb.AppendFormat("Group-Teacher: {0}-{1} ", p.Key, p.Value);
                sb.AppendLine();
            }
        }

        sb.AppendFormat("Fitness: {0}\r\n", FitnessValue);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// План на час
/// </summary>
class HourPlan
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Хранит пару группа-преподаватель
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<int, int> GroupToTeacher = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Хранит пару преподаватель-группа
    /// </summary>
    public Dictionary<int, int> TeacherToGroup = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    public bool AddLesson(int group, int teacher)
    {
        if (TeacherToGroup.ContainsKey(teacher) || GroupToTeacher.ContainsKey(group))
            return false;//в этот час уже есть пара у препода или у группы

        GroupToTeacher[group] = teacher;
        TeacherToGroup[teacher] = group;

        return true;
    }

    public void RemoveLesson(int group, int teacher)
    {
        GroupToTeacher.Remove(group);
        TeacherToGroup.Remove(teacher);
    }

    public HourPlan Clone()
    {
        var res = new HourPlan();
        res.GroupToTeacher = new Dictionary<int, int>(GroupToTeacher);
        res.TeacherToGroup = new Dictionary<int, int>(TeacherToGroup);

        return res;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Пара
/// </summary>
class Lessоn
{
    public byte Day = 255;
    public byte Hour = 255;
    public int Group;
    public int Teacher;

    public Lessоn(byte day, byte hour, int group, int teacher)
        : this(group, teacher)
    {
        Day = day;
        Hour = hour;
    }

    public Lessоn(int group, int teacher)
    {
        Group = group;
        Teacher = teacher;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `...что существуют занятия, в которых ведут сразу два преподавателя? ` - но ведь эти пары преподов не возникают случайным образом, они ведь предопределены каким-то образом или нет? Если бы к вашей программе прилагались еще модульные тесты, то тогда можно было бы быстро разобраться что к чему, а так... Ну может у кого и будет свободное время и  желание разбираться в вашем коде.

Comment: Они прописаны в учебном плане, то что большинство пар группа работает вместе, а остальные делится на подгруппы и идёт к разным преподавателям. А в коде генетический алгоритм на основе пар группа-преподаватель он распределяет занятия, так чтобы и преподаватель был свободен и группа, при этом он получает "штрафы" за окна у преподавателя и у группы, а также за пары позднее заданной. Я недавно начал заниматься с C# и поэтому не знаю, что такое модульные тесты и как их писать, если вам нужны входные данные (примерные), то вот они https://disk.yandex.ru/d/bAPf0P_IKkVvTw?w=1.